# Display the result of stored procedure in GridView with checkbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I need to display the results of a stored procedure in a gridview with checkbox. But my result set is not getting bound to the gridview as I am working on an existing portal which has got the connection strings built in as a dll. Here is my code..

```
protected void Go_Rgn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SecurityController SC = new SecurityController();
    plhTable.Visible = true;
    plhChoose.Visible = false;
    plhForm.Visible = false;
    string Rgn = afRgn.Text;
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    dt=SC.BindGridView(Rgn);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        gvAll.DataSource = dt;
        gvAll.DataBind();
    }
}
```

The compiler throws an error that

> Cannot convert type void to System.Data.DataTable

Please advise me on this.

**DataAccess Layer:**

```
public DataTable BindGridView(string rgn)
{
    string spdName = "spd_get_default_region";
    DbCommand cmd = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(spdName);
    DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "Rgn", DbType.String, rgn);
    return  DB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to return a void when the expected output is a Data Table:

The error is at line:

```
return  m_WorkoutPortal_DB.ExecuteNonQuery(cmd);
```

ExecuteNonQuery does not return a Data Table

Edit:

```
public DataTable BindGridView(string rgn)
{
    string spdName = "spd_get_default_region";

    DbCommand cmd = m_WorkoutPortal_DB.GetStoredProcCommand(spdName);
    m_WorkoutPortal_DB.AddInParameter(cmd, "Rgn", DbType.String, rgn);

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); // Create a SQL Data Adapter and assign it the cmd value. 

    DataTable dt = new DataTable(); // Create a new Data table
    da.Fill(dt); // Fill the data table with the results from the query

    return dt; // return the data table
 }


protected void Go_Rgn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  SecurityController SC = new SecurityController();
  plhTable.Visible = true;
  plhChoose.Visible = false;
  plhForm.Visible = false;
  string Rgn = afRgn.Text;

  gvAll.DataSource = SC.BindGridView(Rgn);
  gvAll.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: @user1080139 looks like you need a SQLDataAdapter.  I will reedit my post to show you how to achieve this.

Comment: I am getting error at this line dt=SC.BindGridView(Rgn); "Cannot implicitly convert type void to System.Data.DataTable

Comment: @user1080139 Are you sure BindGridView has a return type of DataTable and not void?

Comment: Did you use my code? - My code does not return anything other than a DataTable

Comment: @user1080139 - I have edited my answer to include a different version of Go_Rgn_Click.  Implement this and see what you get.

Comment: Now it's showing error in this line.. SqlDataAdapter=new SqlDataAdapter(cmd); has some invalid arguments